# Parse CIM_DateTime to .Net DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

My application is receiving some date information from WMI.  This in the form of strings with the following format:

```
yyyymmddHHMMSS.mmmmmmsUUU
```

For more details on this format, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387237%28VS.85%29.aspx).  I'm interested in parsing everything before the period. I have the following code:

```
    string testDate = "20010701212212"; // July, 01, 2001 21:22:12, in the format specified above
    string format = "yyyyMMddHHmmSS";
    CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    DateTime newDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, format, culture);
```

This always fails on the call to ParseExact(), with an exception stating that "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's almost correct. You want the following format string:

```
yyyyMMddHHmmss
```

i.e. Two-digit seconds is represented by lower-case "ss".

Answer (score 11):

Use [ManagementDateTimeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementdatetimeconverter.aspx).ToDateTime()

Credit goes to Uros Calakovic from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351483/what-format-is-this-time-value-in) question.