# Unable to see the decompiled code of System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(string) using ILSpy/Reflector?

Tags: c#, .net, reflector, ilspy

I am trying to see the actual implementation detail of System.Management.**ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime**(string) using ILspy? It didn't show anything. Then I thought it's probably a bug in ILSpy and tried to see the decompiled code using Reflector - but it also doesn't show details (please see below code snippet) either.

Basically I am trying to see how the cim datetime will be parsed - for details, you may refer to: ([What format is this time value in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351483/what-format-is-this-time-value-in) , [Parse CIM_DateTime to .Net DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717758/parse-cim-datetime-to-net-datetime) )

**Questions**

1. Why am I not able to see the decompiled code of this specific function/assembly?
2. any details on how managementdatetimeconverter parses the stringof type CIM DateTime?

---

```
// System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter
/// <summary>Converts a given DMTF datetime to <see cref="T:System.DateTime" />. The returned <see cref="T:System.DateTime" /> will be in the current time zone of the system.          </summary>
/// <returns>A <see cref="T:System.DateTime" /> that represents the given DMTF datetime.</returns>
/// <param name="dmtfDate">A string representing the datetime in DMTF format.</param>
public static DateTime ToDateTime(string dmtfDate)
{
}
```

Comment: You'll need a better decompiler.  Just use the [published source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Management/ManagementDatetime.cs#18028db43b6fa364) instead.  Comments are always nice.

Comment: I can't answer your question but I can verify that it works on my machine.  I see the decompiled source in ILSpy for System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConvert.ToDateTime(string)

Comment: Works on my machine with Reflector... Are you using an old version?

Comment: thanks for the quick response - they helped me to find details. please see below answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments - it helped me to find a way to see the implementation of `ToDateTim(..)` am looking for.

Visual Studio properties windows showing the system.management assembly location as 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\**System.Management.dll**'. So, I have used this to reflect over to see the implementation.

Once I saw the above comments, which confirms its working for others, I tried to see which assembly has been loaded during runtime - Debug + Modules window showed that the assembly has been loaded from
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\**System.Management.dll**" - so reflecting over it showed that actual code.

Comment: The .NET 4.x reference assemblies are special, they just contain the declarations, no code.

Comment: ohh, for 4.5 Microsoft intentionally hiding implementation details? can I change the behavior? I thought managed code by default can be decompiled - or, its probably one of the configuration to hide these details? do you mind giving more details? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With ILSpy, you can also load the assembly from the GAC.

Menu "File > Open from GAC..."